# Any reason for getting this error? facing an issue in viewing ryu topology viewer

Tags: python, networking, automation, sdn, ryu

hub: uncaught exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ryu/lib/hub.py", line 60, in _launch
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ryu/controller/controller.py", line 211, in server_loop
    server = StreamServer((CONF.ofp_listen_host,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ryu/lib/hub.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.server = eventlet.listen(listen_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/eventlet/convenience.py", line 78, in listen
    sock.bind(addr)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Comment: A service tries to bind to a address/port combination that is already in use by another service (or an other instance of the service).

Comment: @KlausD.  when i typed ps, there's only 1 process is running under that pid. I killed it and tried it again and still the same error comes.